# PayPal express checkout integration with multiple buttons on one page

Tags: javascript, paypal, express-checkout

I currently have a list of items with a Paypal button associated with each of them. Each item will be purchased separately by clicking on its associated button.

```
<ul>
    <li data-id="1">Item 1 <div class="paypal-button"></div></li>
    <li data-id="2">Item 2 <div class="paypal-button"></div></li>
    <li data-id="3">Item 3 <div class="paypal-button"></div></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>

<script>
    paypal.Button.render({
        // options
    }, '.paypal-button');
</script>
```

Unfortunately, it seems that `paypal.Button.render()` will only render the first element that it finds.

Is it possible to do this call on multiple elements?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to give each element a unique id, then call render multiple times:

```
<ul>
    <li data-id="1">Item 1 <div id="button-1"></div></li>
    <li data-id="2">Item 2 <div id="button-2"></div></li>
    <li data-id="3">Item 3 <div id="button-3"></div></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>

<script>
    [ '#button-1', '#button-2', '#button-3' ].forEach(function(selector) {
        paypal.Button.render({
            // options
        }, selector);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I ended up with a similar approach. Kinda ugly, oh well.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't like keeping track of IDs like me, you can use classes instead. And use data attributes to differentiate.

```
<div class="paypal-button" data-my-attribute="tree"></div>
<div class="paypal-button" data-my-attribute="dog"></div>
<div class="paypal-button" data-my-attribute="car"></div>

<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>

<script>
    document.querySelectorAll('.paypal-button').forEach(function(selector) {
        paypal.Button.render({
            // options
            console.log( selector.dataset.myAttribute );
        }, selector);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: is `selector` a variable at the end of `paypal.Button.render`?

Comment: Indeed, it is a variable that holds the element that gets passed from the wrapping forEach loop. [Check the docs about forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: I'm getting an error after trying this.. it says, `Uncaught Error: Document is ready and element [object Object] does not exist`.. any ideas?

Comment: Can you share a reduced test case on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io)? Then I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: You are a savior.